# How can I disable comments and likes on my profile picture on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I want people to be able to see my profile picture without feeling the need to like it and comment about it.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is change the privacy setting of your profile pic to viewable by "**Only Me**". That means your friends and the general public will only be able to see the thumbnail version of your profile pic, they will not be able to click on it and like it or comment on it.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is same as I already have answered. There is nothing new.

Comment: My answer is written in correct English, makes sense and has a screenshot to illustrate the answer

Comment: This screenshot is from 2013. Is "only me" still listed?

Comment: no the screenshot is not from 2013 its from 2017, 2013 is the year that the profile picture was originally posted

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable the comments and likes for all friends. You can do it for specific people if want to do that. What you can do is change the profile picture and set the privacy setting to "Only Me". This way no of your friends will see the update on their Timeline, so there is no chance to like and comment until they do not click on your profile. Friends can it in the thumbnail profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

I can still see my friend's profile picture (not the generic one).  But when I tapped on her profile picture, the Like and Comment are not even there.  I checked my friends list and she is still there.