# How can I disable the like button on my Facebook profile picture

Tags: facebook

I don’t use Facebook a lot but I just posted a profile picture to update the old one I had. But not a lot of my friends use Facebook anymore so I didn’t get a lot of likes on my post. I would like to hide the numbers of like and disable the ability to like my picture and comment on it.

Can I do this? And if yes, how?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/109332/87130

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change the visibility of your current profile picture from "public" to "only me". Your profile picture will then still appear beneath your cover image inside of that squared or circular frame. But, if clicked through other fb profiles, it will be only enlarged without the functionality "Like / Comment / Share".